# Error when trying to skip projects using SonarQube Scanner for Gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have been following this guide to configure Sonar for our project:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

This is a multi module project where we have a master project on the same level as the submodules, e.g:

```
master/build.gradle
sub1/build.gradle
sub2/build.gradle
```

Sonar is configured using mostly default properties:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

  sonarqube {
    properties {
      property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.1.2:9000/"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So I try to skip one of the projects by adding this block (below subprojects):

```
project(":sub2") {
  sonarqube {
    skipProject = true
  }
}
```

But when executing "gradle sonarqube" from the master project I get this exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.checkMandatoryProperties(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:331)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineRootProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:187)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:132)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:35)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:230)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:118)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:98)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 71 more
```

What am I doing wrong? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you've applied the sonarqube configuration in the root project as:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

  sonarqube {
    properties {
      property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.1.2:9000/"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

But you are trying to run the task `sonarqube` from the root project, which is not configured, since you've done it just for subprojects. Try to run this task for the specified project, as `gradle :sub1:sonarqube` or create a custom task in the root project depending on the subprojects `sonarqube` tasks, which will run them all.